# How do i model Jtable data on another row if data length is greater then column size?

Tags: java, swing

image 1:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY93q.jpg]

image 2:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jKb1.jpg]

```
ResultSet Rs = pstm.executeQuery();
    while(Rs.next()){
        model.addRow(new Object[]{Rs.getString(1),Rs.getString(2), Rs.getString(3),Rs.getString(4)});
       }
```

i am using this java code to display data on jtable. i get the result like it shows in image 1, but if the contents is greater then coulmn size it should be added to another row just like image 2. any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom TableCellRender and apply that to your JTable